# Updating the table multiple times using D3 does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a page that need to load a new data and update it to an existing table element using d3. I am writing the following but didn't work:

```
  // completeTableData = [ {head1:va1, head2: val2}, {haed1: val4, head2: val5}, ... ]
  var tr = d3.select("tbody")
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(completeTableData);   
  tr.exit().remove();                       // remove the previous data in the table
  tr.merge(tr.enter().append("tr"));

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    td.data(function(d, i) { 
      return Object.values(d);
    });  
  td.exit().remove();
  td.merge(td.enter().append("td"));
```

It looks like `tr` updates correctly but the `td` always reflects on the previous data and didn't get updated.

Comment: Hi Jes, without seeing more of the code in action, it is difficult to judge what's going on. Could you create a JSFiddle/Codepen with an example of what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Selections in D3 are *immutable*. Therefore, this:

```
tr.merge(tr.enter().append("tr"));
```

... won't change what `tr` is. Since you obviously want it to be the "update + enter" selections, you have to reassign it:

```
tr = tr.merge(tr.enter().append("tr"));
```

Finally, I'd advise naming the enter selection, so the whole thing would be:

```
var trEnter = tr.enter().append("tr");
tr = tr.merge(trEnter);
```